# Why did Allah let humans create other religions?

Tags: other-religions

Allah created humans to worship him. So, why are there other religions with different gods present today ? And some religions are made up by humans, if so why did Allah let them to do it?

And should the people choose their religion intellectually based upon the various religious texts? If yes, wouldn’t it mean that he is testing the intelligence of his own creation ( I mean is he doubtful in our intelligence  ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Good point, and yes he is testing us, not only our intelligence but everything, in fact this is the meaning of life, it's to win or to loose the test, our intelligence is superior to other creatures, and it gives us the possibility to choose, so we should've be responsible of our path and accept the penalty.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly every person was born in religion Islam, all new born children are muslims. But their parents christen to another religion or when they grow up they will choose the religion. Allah subhanahu wa ta'ala created us to test our deeds. In surah Al-Mulk(2nd verse):
**He is the One˺ Who created death and life in order to test which of you is best in deeds. And He is the Almighty, All-Forgiving.**